# Combo box with ability to constraint displayed items. WinForms

Tags: .net, winforms

Hi I need a combo box control (.NET, WinForms) and to be able to constraint available combo box values by typing a string of characters and have those apply a contains/like search to constrain the available values in the combo box. I mean entering "Un" will show me "United Kingom", "United States"...
Can you please advise any existent implementations?

Comment: Do you want to search only the prefix value or in the entire string of the combo box value? for example in the latter case, a search for 'un' would show "Cancun" in addition to "United Kingom", "United States". In the former case, AutoCompleteMode property suggested by @Harvey should suffice.

Comment: Yeah, AutoCompleteMode looks fine but the problem is I need the latter case you described ;)

Answer (score 1):

This feature is provided in the System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.  Check out the [AutoCompleteMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.autocompletemode.aspx)

To do the things you described, you need to set the Items property of the ComboxBox to have all your options "United Kingdom", "United States", etc.  Then, change the AutoCompleteMode to "SuggestAppend".  Change the AutoCompleteSource to "ListItems"

Comment: I've checked autocomplete mode but the problem is I need it work slightly different: for 'un' it should show 'United Kingdom' AND 'Cancun', you see?